# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in backoffice when running Prestashop in Docker

Tags: docker, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to make a docker environment for a Prestashop project. I have it almost working but for some reason, the back office is inaccessible - it gives me a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

I changed the urls in `shop_url` table and changed PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL to no vain. I tried to disable friendly URLs, enable/disable SSL - but the problem persists.

I'm using a custom image for a webserver:

`luken-wodby-nginx-prestashop` Dockerfile:

```
FROM wodby/nginx:1.10

ENV WODBY_DIR_FILES /mnt/files

RUN rm /etc/gotpl/default-vhost.conf.tpl && \
    mkdir -p $WODBY_DIR_FILES && \
    mkdir -p /var/log/nginx

COPY prestashop.conf.tpl /etc/gotpl/
COPY init/* /docker-entrypoint-init.d/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:10.1-2.0.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: organic
      MYSQL_USER: prestashop
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: prestashop
    volumes:
      - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "33060:3306"

  php:
    image: wodby/php:5.6-2.0.0
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      PHP_XDEBUG: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_DEFAULT_ENABLE: 1
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html

  nginx:
    image: luken-wodby-nginx-prestashop:latest
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_NAME: prestashop.docker.localhost
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/public_html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8000:80"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - "8002:8025"
```

Nginx virtual host configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {{ getenv "NGINX_SERVER_NAME" "prestashop" }};
    root {{ getenv "NGINX_SERVER_ROOT" "/var/www/html/" }};
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    index index.php index.html;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 1;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_types application/json text/css application/javascript;

    rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+).(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;
    rewrite ^/order$ /index.php?controller=order last;
    location /panel_adm/ {                           #Change this to your admin folder
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/.*$ /panel_adm/index.php last; #Change this to your admin folder
        }
    }
    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/.*$ /index.php last;
        }
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.*)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass backend;  #Change this to your PHP-FPM location
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }
}
```

Website works just fine, only the back office is inaccessible and gives ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. The `wodby/nginx` nginx container is using a custom `fastcgi_params` file. This file strangely enough doesn't have `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;` line (in contrast to the original file that comes with nginx). This makes it incompatible by default with some ready nginx templates that you can find on the internet. It manifests itself by query parameters not getting passed to the script (I created an issue for it here: https://github.com/wodby/nginx/issues/3 ).

Now, Prestashop's back office not having an important `controller` parameter freaks out, because it doesn't know which controller to run. If there is no controller, it does a redirection to the URL with a default controller as a parameter, but because there is never a "controller" parameter available for Prestashop, it ends in redirection loop causing `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

The fix for this is to add `fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;` in your nginx configuration to pass query parameters to the script.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember, on installation, Prestashop needs to be with full folder permissions, whereas it causes thoses kind of problems.

So for instance :

```
chmod 755 -R /var/www/html
```

should do the job. Do not forget to change the permissions after the installation to something more secure like :

```
chmod 644 -R /var/www/html
chmod 755 -R cache app var modules img
```

(Updated after @abkrim comments on security)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help :( .

Comment: If it would be the case that Prestashop would need chmod 777 -R on /var/www/html, the only action to do would be to remove it in the blink of the eye. This can only be a very bad suggestion and in my very personal opinion giving such suggestions on Stackoverflow does not look helpful to me.

Comment: another response dangerous for community. chmod 777 is very bad solution, and only work in unprofessional servers that using php in mode module instead fcgi or php-fpm.

Comment: @abkrim this is actually a requirement for Prestashop Installation. I totally agree with the fact it should not be that way. Please provide another one if you have it before downvoting blindly.

Comment: @MattLoye This is a requirement ONLY if the server uses old and outdated mod-php. If the server has a modern php-fpm, cgi, fcgi to use PHP on your server, the use of chmod 777 is not only FORBIDDEN, but bad practice, insecure and on many server it can even give error. It is a pity that programmers, still today, talking about the 777, when in reality what it should say is "the XXX directory must have execution and write permissions for the" user "that executes PHP" When they read a little about administration and systems security, maybe you understand the downvote. Best regards.

Comment: I totally agree with your point, however, what do you propose ? I understand you want to be right but this is stack overflow, you shall present a solution somewhere ;). Bad practice is sometimes a necessary evil. Edited anyway following your comments because you are right.