# Problem with redirections ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS prestashop when trying to enter my account section

Tags: php, nginx, prestashop

On my website [lonnatu.com](https://lonnatu.com/), if you try to login, there is a redirection problem that can not be found. 
This URL https://lonnatu.com/my-account redirects to this https://lonnatu.com/inicio-sesion?back=my-account to be able to log in or create an account, but when logging in you should redirect to this https://lonnatu.com/my-account and no longer go back to the other one.

I have come to that it can be a file called `AuthController.php` but I do not know what part I have to change.

```
 class AuthControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $ssl = true;
    public $php_self = 'authentication';
    public $auth = false;

    public function checkAccess()
    {
        if ($this->context->customer->isLogged() && !$this->ajax) {
            $this->redirect_after = ($this->authRedirection) ? urlencode($this->authRedirection) : 'my-account';
            $this->redirect();
        }

        return parent::checkAccess();
    }

    public function initContent()
    {
        $should_redirect = false;

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitCreate') || Tools::isSubmit('create_account')) {
            $register_form = $this
                ->makeCustomerForm()
                ->setGuestAllowed(false)
                ->fillWith(Tools::getAllValues())
            ;

            if (Tools::isSubmit('submitCreate')) {
                $hookResult = array_reduce(
                    Hook::exec('actionSubmitAccountBefore', array(), null, true),
                    function ($carry, $item) {
                        return $carry && $item;
                    },
                    true
                );
                if ($hookResult && $register_form->submit()) {
                    $should_redirect = true;
                }
            }

            $this->context->smarty->assign([
                'register_form' => $register_form->getProxy(),
                'hook_create_account_top' => Hook::exec('displayCustomerAccountFormTop'),
            ]);
            $this->setTemplate('customer/registration');
        } else {
            $login_form = $this->makeLoginForm()->fillWith(
                Tools::getAllValues()
            );

            if (Tools::isSubmit('submitLogin')) {
                if ($login_form->submit()) {
                    $should_redirect = true;
                }
            }

            $this->context->smarty->assign([
                'login_form' => $login_form->getProxy(),
            ]);
            $this->setTemplate('customer/authentication');
        }

        parent::initContent();

        if ($should_redirect && !$this->ajax) {
            $back = urldecode(Tools::getValue('back'));

            if (Tools::urlBelongsToShop($back)) {
                // Checks to see if "back" is a fully qualified
                // URL that is on OUR domain, with the right protocol
                return $this->redirectWithNotifications($back);
            }

            // Well we're not redirecting to a URL,
            // so...
            if ($this->authRedirection) {
                // We may need to go there if defined
                return $this->redirectWithNotifications($this->authRedirection);
            }

            // go home
            return $this->redirectWithNotifications(__PS_BASE_URI__);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _“but I do not know what part I have to change”_ - ideally: None. Core Prestashop files should not need modifying to provide default functionality. This sounds as if the login is not performed properly somehow, so after the login the system still thinks you’re not actually logged in, and therefor redirects back to the login mask again … so this needs some debugging to figure out where it is going wrong. I’d start by checking the settings, maybe something is not correct in there. If the domain is not configured properly or something like that, it might set the session cookie wrong.

Comment: @04FS is perfectly right, please do not modify PrestaShop core files to address this issue. Did you try to replicate this store in a local environment (localhost) to check if the issue is still the same? It might be related to cookies, redirects (in Apache/nginx), PHP configuration, etc.

Comment: This can also be a configuration issue. Excuse the bad content we have on the site (e.g. the suggestion to run chmod 777 is just a total mess, never do these things), maybe this answer rings a bell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43791657/367456 ?

Comment: I restored to a previous point and now the problem is not, if it reappears I will update the question with the possible cause, thank you very much for responding.