# Error 302: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Prestashop Back Office

Tags: php, redirect, prestashop, migrating

I would like to set up a local Docker-based development environment for theme and plugin development. The environment would be a copy of the existing store, however, I have encountered an issue.
Despite completing the migration steps and adjusting the configuration settings, I cannot log into PrestaShop Back Office (BO). After migrating the database and setting the store's URLs in the appropriate tables in the database, the store seems to work locally at first sight. However, I can't log into the admin panel because when I try to access the Back Office (from the URL I defined in the PS_FOLDER_ADMIN environment variable in docker-compose.yaml), the site falls into redirect loop (error 302 - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).
Has anyone of you encountered this issue before and is able to help me solve it?

Additional information:

- Prestashop version: 8.1.4
- MySQL version: 5.7

Here's what I've done so far:

- I downloaded a database dump of the existing store.
- I configured docker-compose and set up a clean store locally.
- I imported the downloaded database dump.
- I updated the appropriate values in the PS_CONFIGURATION and PS_SHOP_URL tables.
- I deleted the cache files and even tried deleting the .htaccess file.

Back Office should work without a problem just like the other pages in the store.

The problem persists in different browsers, which rules out a cookie issue.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180563/err-too-many-redirects-in-backoffice-when-running-prestashop-in-docker?rq=2